# Do I need a blank passport page to visit the UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, paperwork, passport-stamps

I already have a long term visit visa but my passport is full. There is space on some pages for an immigration stamp but no entirely blank page.

I am looking for authentic answers from official sources. There isn't enough time for a passport renewal.

Answer (score 3):

Well, official sources aren't normally going to explicitly say when a certain requirement **doesn't** exist.

TIMATIC, the database used by airlines, points out if there is such a requirement for a country (as airlines get fined for transporting inadmissible passengers), but doesn't mention this for the UK.

Therefore, as long as there's space for the entry stamp, you should be fine.